# PowerShell Invoke-Command performance issue

Tags: performance, powershell, powershell-remoting

There are a few computers on my domain that I have access to remote into with PowerShell. I'm getting extremely slow performance when I remote into a particular computer with a command like this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName someComputerName -ScriptBlock { ls C:\ } -credential myUsername
```

It takes about 10 seconds to display each file/folder on the drive. If I run the same command from within a session using Enter-PSSession then there are no performance issues. Also if I run a command like Get-Alias with Invoke-Command there are no performance issues. Lastly I can run any command on any other computer without any performance issues.

Any idea what could be causing this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be a bandwidth issue.  Does this run any faster?

```
convertfrom-csv (Invoke-Command -ComputerName someComputerName -ScriptBlock { ls C:\ | convertto-csv} -credential myUsername)
```

Comment: Yes that command runs almost instantly. Is this faster because the csv representation of these files is much smaller than the object representation? Any idea what could be causing a bandwidth issues like this? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the XML payload for that csv is much smaller than the XML payload for the FileInfo objects.  You can verify this yourself by using export-clixml on both, and noting the file sizes.  You might want to fire up a packet analyzer to see what's going on with the network.